# Concept (Event Broker maybe?)

Tags: c#, .net

Still a bit new to the .NET world. I am trying to accomplish a task. I want to learn it, so a Concept or Theory would be helpful in this. I am thinking this will be using the methodology of an EventBroker.

What I need to do, is create multiple objects that created a TCPclient Connection to different devices. (each object has its own TCPClient and address for that matter).  We will call this object a "Core".  So I have multiple Core objects.

Each one of these Core Objects, can have a multitude of "Items" that need to talk to it (2-Way).

What I want to do, is at initialization, "register" all the Items to their respective Cores.  After that, any Item that has registered to a Core, has it's value/data change, I want it only to send the data to it's hosting Core.  And when Data changes on the Core (a response) send it to the respective Item.

I hope this makes sense.  I am really just looking to be pointed in the right direction. I do Feel, the Event Broker methodology will be my best bet. Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: You can do it manually or just leave it to .NET using WCF.

Comment: You can pass instance of corresponding core to item (e.g. as constructor parameter). Items can subscribe to that instance events (e.g. `DataRecieved`), they will not receive events from other cores. It's not clear what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you'd need some central place for something, but I didn't quite get for what you'd want to do with those objects then. I don't know if you need external users (across internet) to interact with your services, or if intranet scenario is enough.

If those objects need to communicate with each other, you could use a **mediator design pattern** or **event broker**.

If cross-object communication is not needed, then you could use perhaps **service locator pattern** or **pub-sub model**.

I'm hosting a few WCF Services sometimes with just a container that instantiates the needed services in the beginning. This would be a poor-man's centralized solution. It doesn't have by the book you know. :)